# How to move object on x axis smoothly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I want to ask how I can smoothly move object on x axis to left and right ?
I want to move exactly only on X axis where z and y axis will stay the same as before the movement.
I tried with code:

> rb.Transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltatime * 130);

but that teleports the player i want movement to be fast how much i want. 
I want to only add on x axis for example if the object is on

```
0->X
0->Y
0->Z
```

I want to move to right then x axis need to be = 4,When i want to get left if the object is moved right and its on coordinates (4,0,0) I want to get back to (0,0,0) when press the key to get left. When i want one more field left the coordinates need to be (-4,0,0)
I hope someone will get what i want to achieve.

EDIT:

The blue star is player on position , i want to smoothly move to right and left only on x axis where YZ stays the same, on picture is how i want to move, and i want only smoothly movement not teleporting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfPU9.png)

BLUE IS WHERE THE PLAYER IS AND YELLOW&GREEN STAR IS WHERE PLAYER NEED TO GO WHEN IS GOING TO RIGHT OFC WHEN GOING TO LEFT NEED TO BE ON THE SAME POSITION AGAIN ... Thanks

Comment: In how many seconds do you want the translation to take place?

Comment: maybe 0,5 or 1 second .. I did 150 in code because if i put smaller number it will not move on right position so i don't understand something clearly..also this code teleports the player its not smoothly movement i can not see object moving to right just dissapear and appear on the right inmidiatelly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Vector3.Lerp

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Transforms to act as start and end markers for the journey.
    public Transform startMarker;
    public Transform endMarker;

    // Movement speed in units/sec.
    public float speed = 1.0F;

    // Time when the movement started.
    private float startTime;

    // Total distance between the markers.
    private float journeyLength;

    void Start()
    {
        // Keep a note of the time the movement started.
        startTime = Time.time;

        // Calculate the journey length.
        journeyLength = Vector3.Distance(startMarker.position, endMarker.position);
    }

    // Follows the target position like with a spring
    void Update()
    {
        // Distance moved = time * speed.
        float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;

        // Fraction of journey completed = current distance divided by total distance.
        float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;

        // Set our position as a fraction of the distance between the markers.
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startMarker.position, endMarker.position, fracJourney);
    }
}
```

source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

Comment: I don't know how i can implement this to my code and where to define how much it will move on x axis and where to define that i don't change Y and Z axis, btw thank you for fast asnwer

Comment: Then if you want to move left, you could use:

Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * 3f

When i move like that it doesn't moves how much i need to move on x axis...

Comment: when i put smaller number then 150 it will not move on position where i need object , i need excatly on X = 4 when is mooved to right , when is moved to left then same x position - 4

Comment: because, as endMarker you should set a Vector equal to the object starting transform except X which will be 4 units greater.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise you wanted to move to specific co-ordinates. Copy my answer and set startMarker.position to (0,0,0) then endMarker.position (4,0,0). That will get you started. Then you can figure the rest!

Comment: (assuming the object started its journey at 0 0 0)

Answer (score 0):

Every frame, you could create a new Vector3 with the object original z and y and just update the x according to time logic. Then assign this vector to the object transform. This is the simplest way.

Comment: Can you show me code sample for this , if that works and if the object moves smoothly not teleporting i will send you money for beer.

Comment: Now that I understand better, I think you should use the Vector3.Lerp solution posted by the moon is made of cheese. Just add a C# script to your object called ExampleClass (change it later) and paste the code. You will be able to write the values for the public properties in the editor. Later on you will have to tie the event occurrence to the keyboard and no longer to the Start() but that will get you started as a working example.

Comment: I made edit in question to clearly explain in picture what i need to achieve.

Comment: Use the Lerp code, trust me. But what that code does, is always start at 0 0 0. You need to trigger it not on Start() but on keystroke. And startMarker.position should be initialized to object.transform.position ... and endMarker to the same except X 4 units to the right or left. The object will then move. Note: 4 units in 1 second means speed is 0.25

Comment: Moreover, remember to stop the journey when the distance has become very little or zero or the update() will keep running the lerp and recalculate the position.

Comment: Can you write me code what i can actually use in game, this one works but i need to put empty gameobject and in inspector define that gameobject as destination point where player will be teleported i  need when  i press left key to go left 4 on x aaxis and when i press right to go on -4... I don't know how i can edit the code to work how i want, also i don't know how to get object transform position... thanks

Comment: Just define a GameObject public property and drag it in the editor... this way you can use it in the code, its transform position will be the endMarker.. 
And instead to  run it at Start(), just run it in a start function, which you'll call when your event is fired (key stroke, button press in the editor, whatever you like)